# What's the criteria to display the top reputation networks in Developer Story?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Checking the rep section in developer story I realized appears mentioned my top networks:

[image: My networks]

I'm guessing this only consider networks related with I.T., because it doesn't display another networks where I have a higher reputation than my Super User profile, which it makes sense, but I was wondering why it doesn't appears my [SOes rep.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/213/alter-lagos), which is higher than Super User and I guess is completely relevant with my I.T. formation.
Are you considering to add the localized SO versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your Top Network Sites were imported in with your previous Careers CV.  You had set those specific sites to be displayed on your CV.

I've looked through the codebase and it doesn't appear that we automatically select any of the sites for you to display. We leave that up to the user to decide. You can choose them yourself, by editing the personal info section of your Developer Story. You'll be presented with all of the network sites that you have an account on, including the international Stack Overflow sites.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the automatic criteria is, although it may take into consideration that Super User was one of the first sites in the exchange.

There is an option to change them though, and include any exchange you want, even metas.

Just hover the section in your Developer Story, and click the blue "edit" in the top right of the section to get the "chooser"

Mine looks like this

[image]